Re-writing multiple web services URLs using context root in ejb applications on wildfly9 server
When we are trying to deploy ear files (ejb application) on wildfly 9 server, the published web service has artifactid/module name in the URL.
example pom.xml.
example web service url: http://localhost:8080/wildfly-helloworld-ws/HelloWorldService?wsdl
but as in my project need to remove module name from web service url. So tried adding <context-root></context-root> in jboss-webservices.xml file as below :

<webservices xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee/jbossws-web-services_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.1">
  <context-root></context-root>
</webservices>

And this configuration is working as expected for one module which has web services. But in case multi module project where we have multiple modules with web services there when we supply same configuration to all modules which has web services then while deploying ear files facing duplicateServiceException.
Error:
WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "XXXXXXX" of deployment "XXXXXXX"

 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617

Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service `jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./******`.session is already registered

If anyone have faced this type situation and able solve the issue, please help.
Any suggestions on configuring  on global level in the project so that it will be applied to all web services or any other way to achieve the goal of removing module/artifactId from web service URL will be helps a lot.
tried adding <context-root></context-root> in jboss-webservices.xml
